# Wordpress - Shortcode Ignoring External Divs

Tags: html, wordpress-theming, wordpress

I have found a whopper of a problem and I really don't understand what is going on. So I have a div and in that div there is a shortcode nested in there.

Edit: The shortcode is outputting as it should, it is just ignoring all the divs it is nested in and outputting seperately, forcing it above the rest of the content on the page.

For e.g:

```html
<div id="adiv"> [SHORTCODE][/SHORTCODE] </div> <!-- Should output the same way, right? -->
```

Instead it is outputting:

```html
    [SHORTCODE][/SHORTCODE]
    
    <div id="adiv"><div> <!-- Completely ignoring the fact that the shortcode is nested -->
```

I swear I am not a complete noob but this is probably a noob problem. Any and all help is aprreciated. I am baffled to say the least!

Thanks,
Jamsplash

Comment: are you sure there not supposed to be curly braces, I had a plugin that used shortcodes and it was curlies ?

Comment: The shortcode itself is working, it is going to the top of the page. Completely ignoring all the divs around it. I tried curly braces just in case and it wasn't the case this time. Thanks for your help though, i really do appreciate it :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I managed to answer my own question so hope I can help others with the same problem:

```html
/*-------------------------------------------------------------------
 *      Some Shortcodey Thingy
 *------------------------------------------------------------------*/

add_shortcode('thingy','thingy_shortcodes');

function thingy_shortcodes( $atts, $content = null )
{
 extract(shortcode_atts(array( 'category' => '0'),$atts));
 
 ob_start(); <!--- use this to set the content you want to get AKA the stuff you                       want FOR DISPLAY -->
 
 STUFF FOR DISPLAY...... 
    GOES HERE

 $popular = ob_get_contents(); <!-- Set the variable that is going to dispay your                                        STUFF FOR DISPLAY-->
 ob_end_clean();               <!-- Where STUFF FOR DISPLAY ENDS-->

 return $popular;              <!-- Return your content -->
}
```